# Inconsistency in cross-validation results

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a set of dataset recorded from subjects as they perform some particular cognitive task. The data consists of 16 channels and a number of sample points per channel and I want to classify this data according to the cognitive task being performed (everything is labelled).

The issue is that I do not have a large amount of data (approximately 60 trials per session, 30 for each cognitive task) and I have 2 sessions. I am trying to train a Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) classifier to classify this data. The classifier is later to be used in real-time to give some form of output every number of samples.

I made use of a 5-fold cross-validation to measure the generalization error of my classifier. The problem is that when I run this 5-fold cross validation a number of times, the results I get are not constant at all. Instead there's a significant variation in the overall accuracy (for example, first 5-fold cross validation may yield an average accuracy of 80%, 2nd yields an accuracy of 65%, 3rd yields an average of 72% etc...). Is this normal? If not, what could be the causes?

Comment: LDA projects your data into another coordinate system and reduces the dimension. How do you use it for classification?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have some bad data or your classifier is overfitting. You can perform Leave-one-out cross-validation and note your results. It can help to find data that may be biasing the results.